# Diffrent signatures for a file based on freshly createted vs. longer persistence

Tags: android, file, md5

### Context

I am copying a sqlite db file out of the assets to internal storage.
The file opens fine, but I wanted a additional layer of safety.  There is
a slim possibility that when the file gets copied out it doesn't complete.
I decided to favor a check sum technique: specifically the `MessageDigest`
Java thing.  so here's the code:

```
    public ZipCode(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    if (!databaseExist(ctx)) {
        Log.d("ZipCode", "DB DNE");
        inflate_db(ctx);
        check_DB(ctx);
    } else {
        Log.d("ZipCode", "DB Exsits");
        check_DB(ctx);
    }

}
private static void inflate_db(Context ctx) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int length;
        AssetManager am = ctx.getAssets();
        try {
            BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                    am.open(ZIPCODE_SQLITE_FAUX_FILE));
            GZIPInputStream zis = new GZIPInputStream(is);
            File dbfile = ctx.getDatabasePath(ZIPCODE_SQLITE);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dbfile);
            while ((length = zis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            zis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

private static void check_DB(Context ctx) {
        File dbfile = ctx.getDatabasePath(ZIPCODE_SQLITE);
        FileInputStream fis;
        MessageDigest digester;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
        int byteCount;
        try {
            digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            fis = new FileInputStream(dbfile);
            while ((byteCount = fis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                digester.update(bytes, 0, byteCount);
            }
            String digest = Base64.encodeBytes(digester.digest());
            Log.d("MD5 Sum", digest);
            fis.close();
            return;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

### Now for the Question

Why is it that on fresh creation the `check_DB`'s `Log.d("MD5 Sum", digest);`
has one output and say on relaunch (i.e. the DB file exists in internal storage)
the `check_DB`'s `Log.d("MD5 Sum", digest);` has a different output.

#### *Note:*

`databaseExist(ctx)` checks for the DB file's existence per Android conventions.

```
private static boolean databaseExist(Context ctx) {
    File dbFile = ctx.getDatabasePath(ZIPCODE_SQLITE);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

Comment: per @lenik's answer the `check_DB` function has changed to `byteCount = fis.read(bytes)) != -1`,and the initial copy has a md5sum that corresponds to the md5sum of the database file.  The "relaunch" still is different though.

Comment: I have figured out what was happening.  When I extracted the db file from an emulator, I found an android metadata table was created.  I didn't think that any manipulation of the database would occur just by opening it.  Well that's it Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you calculate MD5 of your asset file (in your project directory) to find out which MD5 is right and which is wrong? then it'll be easier to find the problem part.

also, i'd suggest to replace `(byteCount = fis.read(bytes)) > 0` with `(byteCount = fis.read(bytes)) != -1` according to the `FileInputStream` reference manual.

Comment: You were very helpful.  The file copy has the a md5 sum of the database, but the "relaunch" check is still different.  I would of never noticed that -1 thing.  Again, thank you.